# Inserting a table record (log entry) upon CSV download

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm fairly new to PHP and this is my first-ever stackoverflow question:

I want to make it easy for a user to know when data has changed since they last downloaded a CSV file from the application I'm building.  The CSV export works and I can determine whether there are any rows whose timestamp is after the timestamp stored in an export log table.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to store the timestamp in the log table.  When a user clicks the link to export the file, the code below executes to produce the file.  The very last four lines are my attempt to make the log entry.  $con is valid and works and my method works in a regular PHP page, but I can't figure out how to make it work in the CSV download page and I don't know of any other way to make the entry when the user clicks to download.  I am open to ideas for the best way to do this.

I really appreciate your time -- thanks in advance!

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=speakers.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

require_once("../scripts/dbcon.inc.php");
require_once("../scripts/presentersessions.inc.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT sp.person_id, CONCAT(p.person_display_name, ' ', p.person_last_name) person_name, '' session_titles, p.person_bio FROM person p INNER JOIN presenters sp ON p.person_id = sp.person_id ORDER BY p.person_last_name, p.person_display_name";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('failed query:  '.$query);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$output = fopen("php://output", "w");

fputcsv($output, array("Item ID (Optional)","Name","Sub-Title (i.e. Location, Table/Booth, or Title/Sponsorship Level)","Description (Optional)","Location/Room"));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    #echo '"","'.htmlspecialchars($row['person_display_name']).' '.htmlspecialchars($row['person_last_name']).'","'.htmlspecialchars($row['session_title']).'","'.htmlspecialchars($row['person_bio']).'"\n"';
    $person_id = $row['person_id'];
    $row['person_name'] = $row['person_name'];
    $row['session_titles'] = presenter_sessions($conference_id, $person_id);
    $row['person_id'] = '';
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}

date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
$export_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query_insert_log_entry = "INSERT INTO export_log (export_type, export_timestamp, person_id) VALUES ('$export_type', '$export_timestamp', {$_SESSION['valid_accbo_person_id']})";
$result_insert_log_entry = mysqli_query($con, $query_insert_log_entry);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you set this vaiable $export_type and $_SESSION['valid_accbo_person_id'] is accessible on this page.

I think the problem is in this line -

```
$query_insert_log_entry = "INSERT INTO export_log (export_type, export_timestamp, person_id) VALUES ('$export_type', '$export_timestamp', {$_SESSION['valid_accbo_person_id']})";
```

remove those single quote from variables like below -

```
$query_insert_log_entry = "INSERT INTO export_log (export_type, export_timestamp, person_id) VALUES ('{$export_type}', '{$export_timestamp}', '{$_SESSION['valid_accbo_person_id']}')";
```

Comment: Thanks, Selim.  The two variables are valid;  this works if I test it in a regular webpage.  The single quotes are needed by the SQL statement because those are string values being inserted into the database.  However, I tried it just in case and it still did not work.  Thanks again!

Comment: How about this one - $query_insert_log_entry = "INSERT INTO export_log (export_type, export_timestamp, person_id) VALUES ('{$export_type}', '{$export_timestamp}', '{$_SESSION['valid_accbo_person_id']}')";

Comment: Selim, I discovered the problem and it's working now.  You asked me to check whether $_SESSION['valid_accbo_person_id'] was valid and I told you it was.  Well, it was as long as I was testing in the same browser tab.  Once I launch a new browser tab, it is not valid, so I passed the value in the URL, read it via $_REQUEST, and all is working now.  Thanks so much!